# How to find 2 largest values from group of rows in multiple columns in Python and also show its row and column index without duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matrix

I am new to Python. I want to find the largest values from all the columns for repetitive row elements (i.e. 5 to 150), and also show its row and column index label in output.The largest values should be absolute. (Irrespective of + or - sign). 
The group of row indexes will keep on repeating for 'n'number of times. For every 'nth' group of row index, I want 'n' largest values and their index positions for each group.
Also if the largest value of a certain index is repeated in different groups, then program must allocate that index to the group having largest value of the two. 
There should not be duplicates for row indexes in different groups.

My dataset:
[image: Mydataset]

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'0_deg': [43, 50, 45, -17, 5, 8, 9, 19, 11, 32, 36, 41, 10, 1, 19, 11, 32, 36, 1, 8, 9], 
              '10_deg': [47, 41, 46, -18, 4, 5, 11, 16, 12, 34, -52, 31, 23, 4, 16, 12, 34, -71, 2, 7, 10], 
              '20_deg': [46, 43, -56, 29, 6, 7, 10, 14, 13, 33, 43, 6, 9, -40, 14, 13, 37, 43, 3, 6, 11], 
              '30_deg': [-46, 16, -40, -11, 9, 1, 12, 15, 33, -39, -22, 21, 23, 14, 15, 63, -39, -22, 4, 5, 12]}, index=[5, 10, 12, 101, 130, 140, 150, 5, 10, 12, 101, 130, 140, 150, 5, 10, 12, 101, 130, 140, 150])

df = df.set_index('Number')
```

```
def f(x):
    x1 = x.abs().stack()
    x2 = x.stack()
    x = x2.iloc[np.argsort(-x1)].head(b)
    return x

groups = (df.index == 5).cumsum()
df1 = df.groupby(groups).apply(f).reset_index(level=[1,2])
df1.columns = ['Number','Angle','Value']
print (df1)
```

Expected Result:

[image: Expectedoutput]

Actual Result:

[image: Actualoutput]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need two `groupby` filter

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['key']=df['index'].eq(5).cumsum()
s=df.melt(['key','index'])
s=s[(-s.value.abs()).groupby(s['index']).rank()==1]
# just need select max row of each index before pick two from the each group
s[(-s.value.abs()).groupby(s.key).rank()<=2].sort_values('key')
Out[672]: 
    key  index variable  value
21    1      5   10_deg     47
44    1     12   20_deg    -56
11    2    130    0_deg     41
55    2    150   20_deg    -40
38    3    101   10_deg    -71
78    3     10   30_deg     63
```

Comment: Thanks. But the output is not showing groupwise i.e. the 'key' column is showing in the order ```2 1 3 1 2 3``` The order should be ```1 1 2 2 3 3```